# Reverse for 'sales' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['sales/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Tags: django

I have seen a lot of relatable questions and answers,  I just haven't understood even after tweaking my code why it doesn't seem to respond. I am new to django, I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Views.py

```
@login_required
def add_user_sales(request , pk):
    current_user = request.user
    context = {}
    context["data"] = MadeSale.objects.get(id=pk)
    profiles = UserProfile.get_profile()
    for profile in profiles:
        if profile.profile_name.id == current_user.id:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SalesForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    upload = form.save(commit=False)
                    upload.posted_by = current_user
                    upload.profile = profile
                    upload.save()
                    messages.success(request, f'Hi, Your data has successfully been updated' )
                    return redirect('addProduct')
            else:
                form = SalesForm()
            return render(request,'addProduct.html',{"user":current_user,"form":form}, context)
```

linked url

```
<nav class="navbar" style="margin-left: auto;">
        <ul class="ul" style="margin-left: auto;">
            <li class="li"><a href="{% url 'user' %}">Home</a></li>

            <li class="li"><a href="{% url 'sales'add_user_sales.pk %}">Sales</a></li> ***(This line is the culprit)***
            <li class="li"><a href="{% url 'total' %}">Total</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="{% url 'margin' %}">Margin</a></li>

            
            <!-- For DevelopmentPurposes -->

            <li class="li"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/">Admin Dashboard</a></li> 
            <li class="li"><a href="{% url 'monthlyTotal' %}">Total</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

my url

```
url(r'sales/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.add_user_sales, name='sales'),
```

Comment: There should be a space between `'sales'` and `add_user`, so `{% url 'sales' add_user_sales.pk %}`.

Comment: in your template try adding a space after url 'sales'

Comment: Thank you guys . Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing space in your `url` templatetag

```
{% url 'sales'add_user_sales.pk %}
```

needs to be

```
{% url 'sales' add_user_sales.pk %}
```